# Xcode and Firestore: How to round query

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I am trying to make a graph with `Charts` in Xcode.

This is the way I submit data with another script:

```
    {
        recordSubmissionId()

        
        //Check the calories are in good format
        if let calories = Int(InputedCalories.text ?? "0")
        {
            let submissionRequest =
            Submission(
                 userId:                        customerID,
                 customerEmail:                 Auth.auth().currentUser?.email ?? "",
                 submitID:                      submissionID,
                 date:                          String("\(EnteredDateAndTime.date)"),
                 caloriesAmount:                calories,
                 comment:                       InputedText.text ?? "no comment")
    
            do {
                // Encode the submission struct as JSON data
                let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(submissionRequest)
                
                // Convert the JSON data to a dictionary
                guard let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                else
                {
                    return
                }
                
                // Write the dictionary to the Firestore database
                db.collection("submissions").document("\(submissionID)").setData(dictionary)
                {
                    error in
                    if let error = error
                    {
                        print("Error writing data: \(error)")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("Document added successfully!")
                    }
                }
            }
            catch let error
            {
                print("Error encoding data: \(error)")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fatalError("Calories are entered with a String format")
        }
    }
```

and this is the way I am trying to get this data back.

```
import UIKit
import Charts
import Firebase

class HistoryController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myBarChart: BarChartView!
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let MSC = MainSectionController()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        firebaseExport()
        barVisualisation()
    }
    
    // Create the bar and data for it
    func barCreation(submissions: [[Any]]) {
        var dataEntries = [BarChartDataEntry]()
        var dates = [String]()
        
        for i in 0..<submissions.count {
            let submission = submissions[i]
            if let date = submission[0] as? String, let caloriesAmount = submission[1] as? Int {
                let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(caloriesAmount))
                dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
                dates.append(date)
            }
        }
        
        myBarChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: dates)
        
        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "Weight")
        let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
        myBarChart.data = chartData
        
        chartDataSet.colors = [.blue, .green, .red]
    }
    
    // Add additional fancy visualization
    func barVisualisation() {
        myBarChart.animate(yAxisDuration: 2.0)
        
        // Set Y-axis limits and description
        myBarChart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
        myBarChart.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 100.0
        myBarChart.leftAxis.labelCount = 5
        myBarChart.leftAxis.axisLineColor = .black
        myBarChart.leftAxis.labelTextColor = .black
        myBarChart.rightAxis.enabled = false
        
        // Set X-axis description
        myBarChart.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        myBarChart.xAxis.labelTextColor = .black
        myBarChart.xAxis.axisLineColor = .black
        myBarChart.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
        myBarChart.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
        myBarChart.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = -45
    }
    
    // Import data from database
    func firebaseExport() {
        db.collection("submissions")
            .whereField("userID", isEqualTo: MSC.customerID)
            .order(by: "date")
            .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, error) in
                
                if let snapshot = querySnapshot {
                    print("Number of documents: \(snapshot.documents.count)")
                }
                
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
                } else {
                    var submissionsByDate = [String: Int]()
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let date = data["date"] as! String
                        let caloriesAmount = data["caloriesAmount"] as! Int
                        
                        let calendar = Calendar.current
                        if let dateObj = DateFormatter().date(from: date) {
                            let roundedDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: dateObj)
                            let roundedDateString = DateFormatter().string(from: roundedDate)
                            
                            if let existingCalories = submissionsByDate[roundedDateString] {
                                submissionsByDate[roundedDateString] = existingCalories + caloriesAmount
                            } else {
                                submissionsByDate[roundedDateString] = caloriesAmount
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // check if there is any data
                    if submissionsByDate.isEmpty {
                        print("No data available")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    print("Submissions by date: \(submissionsByDate)")
                    let sortedSubmissions = submissionsByDate.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
                    let submissionData = sortedSubmissions.map { [$0.key, $0.value] }
                    print("Submission data: \(submissionData)")
                    
                    self.barCreation(submissions: submissionData)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

My ultimate goal is to mahe the barChar, which will round the data:
Like:
21.04.23 total SUM of calories = 430
22.04.23 total SUM of calories = -200

and it could be, that there were 50 submissions on 21.04.23 and only one on 22.04.23 - I need the result to be rounded by day and with total SUM of calories.

Spent already 30h - still no result....

Comment: If you make a model you can do dictionary grouping